# E-mail Marketing não reconhece margin

Tags: html, email

Estou estudando e-mail marketing. Estou tentando colocar um texto em uma parte branca quadrada no meio da imagem. Porém, percebi que não está reconhecendo o elemento `margin` nos e-mails. Alguma alternativa?

Preciso deixar o texto no meio da imagem no marketing e-mail.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 

    <tr> 

        <td width="600">

            <img src="images/Header.png" width="600" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 9999;">

        </td> 

    </tr>



    <tr> 

        <td width="600">

            <img src="images/fundo.png" width="600" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; position: relative; margin-top: -43px; z-index: -9999;">

        </td> 

    </tr>

    <tr> 

        <td width="600">

            <p id="text-box" style="position: relative; width: 250px; margin-top: -400px; text-align: justify;">

             <span style="margin-left: 60px;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 20px;">Mês das Mães!</span> </br>
                Nesse mês especial, todos os eventos realizados com o nosso <strong><a href="http://www.buffetcrepemania.com.br/index.php/buffet-de-crepe/" target="_blank" style="color:#36F;">Buffet de Crepe</a></strong> levam uma opção exclusiva: <strong>Crepe de Carne Seca com Cheddar!</strong></br>
                Além disso, todas as mães no evento ganham um brigadeiro delicioso!</br>
                Não perca tempo! Aproveite nossa promoção e peça um orçamento! Ligue para <strong>11. 4135-2620 </strong>ou <a href="http://www.buffetcrepemania.com.br/index.php/fale-conosco/" target="_blank" style="color:#36F;">envie uma mensagem pelo site</a>.</p>

        </td> 

    </tr>

    <tr> 

        <td width="600">

            <img src="images/transicao.png" width="600" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; position: relative; z-index: 9999; margin-bottom: -10px;">

        </td> 

    </tr>



    <tr style="display: inline-block;">  

        <td width="150" id="td-img0"><a href="http://www.buffetcrepemania.com.br/index.php/buffet-de-crepe/"><img src="images/servico1.png" width="150" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;"></a>
        </td> 

        <td width="150" id="td-img1"><a href="http://www.buffetcrepemania.com.br/index.php/coffe-break/"><img src="images/servico2.png" width="150" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;"></a>

        </td> 

        <td width="150" id="td-img2"><a href="http://www.buffetcrepemania.com.br/index.php/quem-somos/"><img src="images/servico3.png" width="150" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;"></a>

        </td>   

        <td width="150" id="td-img3"><a href="http://www.buffetcrepemania.com.br/index.php/quem-somos/"><img src="images/servico4.png" width="150" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block;"></a>

        </td> 

    </tr>

    <tr> 

        <td width="600">

            <img src="images/Footer.png" width="600" height="auto" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; position: relative; margin-top: -5px;">

        </td> 

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Mostre como esta seu código, onde exatamente esta tendo dificuldade com o email marketing?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho  Coloquei o codigo.

Comment: Acho bem interessante verificar as tags, por esse site ->https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @David diz que margin funciona, mas comigo não ta funcionando.

Comment: Hospeda suas imagens em algum lugar, e coloque seu código no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) ou [Codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/), e coloque o link de compartilhamento no seu post, assim conseguimos visualizar melhor :)

Comment: Lembre-se de que muitos sistemas de email hoje são acessados via navegador, como GMail e Hotmail. Esses sistemas tendem a fazer uma "limpeza" do seu markup, removendo tudo que não for compatível com eles. Focar muito na formatação do seu email pode ser um esforço perdido.